# How use numpy.bincount with a weight vector of non-built-in type?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `numpy.bincount`, and I have a vector of indices `ind`, and a vector of weights `coef`, trying to run `np.bincount(ind, coef)`. The problem here is that my weight vector is not of type float64, it is a non-built-in class supporting the arithmetic operator `__add__`.

I wonder how I can do this? Directly run the code `np.bincount(ind, coef)` gives me an error that

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

The specific type I am considering is `LaruentPolynomailRing` from Sagemath.

Comment: This is just not possible. Numpy uses C internally to do its fast operations, so it has a list of types that it supports. Could you show some code, such as the definition of your class and its `__add__` function? Perhaps something else could be done.

Comment: Even when they work, math on object dtype arrays is much slower, since it has to iterate at list comprehension speeds

Comment: @user17242583 Thanks for your comments. I have added some info. In particular, the type I am considering is from a math library called Sagemath, and the exact type is `LaurentPolynomialRing`.

Comment: @hpaulj That is what I have to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bincount` is compiled code, so we can't (readily) see what it does; we can only deduce things from the behavior.

The basic count:

```
In [303]: np.bincount(x)
Out[303]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

But adapting the weight example, to provide an `int` array of weights:

```
In [304]: #w = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 1., -0.6]) # weights
     ...: w = np.array([3,5,2,7,10,-6])
     ...: x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
     ...: np.bincount(x,  weights=w)
Out[304]: array([ 3.,  7., 11.])
```

This is consistent with your error.  The result is float, even when weights are int. Weights have been converted to float.

It might do something like this - but compiled code:

```
In [306]: res = np.zeros(3)
In [307]: for i,v in zip(x,w):
     ...:     res[i] += v
     ...: 
In [308]: res
Out[308]: array([ 3.,  7., 11.])
```

I'm guessing this because it returns a result for each integer value between the `x.min` and `x.max`.  Written like this it just requires `w` to have the `__add__`.  But this kind of iteration on object dtype array is slow, even in compiled code - since it has to use to `__add__` of each element object.  It can't just zip through the byte data-buffer of the `w` array.

Without the consecutive bin value constraint, a `defaultdict` is an easy tool for collecting like values.

```
In [309]: from collections import defaultdict
In [310]: dd = defaultdict(float)
In [311]: for i,v in zip(x,w):
     ...:     dd[i] += v
     ...: 
In [312]: dd
Out[312]: defaultdict(float, {0: 3.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 11.0})
```

another way -again where `x` values are indices in the return array:

```
In [313]: res = np.zeros(3)
In [315]: np.add.at(res, x, w)
In [316]: res
Out[316]: array([ 3.,  7., 11.])
```

I think all these will work with the objects with `__add__`.

Comment: np.add.at also requires float, gives me an error as: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'sage.rings.polynomial.laurent_polynomial.LaurentPolynomial_univariate'.

Comment: I think the dictionary implementation is great, it's just this is not vectorized and I am pretty worried about this.

Comment: As long as your weights are in an array/list of objects, it can't be "vectorized".  The numeric weight values have to be accessed individual for each object.  `numpy` "vectorized" means using compiled numpy code with numeric dtype arrays.

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot for all the infos.